# Printing a linked list?

Tags: c

When running the following code my system hangs. I am trying to understand the basics of linked lists and linked list manipulation. Could someone please explain to me what I did wrong (don't understand). Thanks guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct ListNodeT
{
    float power;
    struct ListNodeT *nextPtr;

}ListNodeType;

void ReadFileList(ListNodeType *Data);

int main(void)
{
    ListNodeType a;

    ReadFileList(&a);

    ListNodeType *node = &a;

    do
    {
        printf("%f", node->power);
        node = node->nextPtr;

    }while(node != NULL);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void ReadFileList(ListNodeType *Data)
{

    ListNodeType new[2];


    Data->nextPtr = &new[0];
    new[0].nextPtr = &new[1];
    new[1].nextPtr = NULL;

    Data->power = 0.1;
    new[0].power = 1.2;
    new[1].power = 2.3;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadFileList is creating an array of ListNodeType structures on the stack, once that function call ends those variables go out of scope.  You can use malloc to allocate memory.

Answer (score 4):

You're filling in `Data` in `ReadFileList` with pointers to local variables.  Those go out of scope when `ReadFileList` returns, so you cause undefined behaviour.